# websocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/room_page/5/' failed: Error during websocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to make a real-time chat system, but it gives me an error in console log:

> websocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/room_page/5/' failed: Error during websocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Also, in the vs code terminal, it says:

```
[17/May/2023 20:05:38] "GET /room_page/5/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9806
Not Found: /ws/room_page/5/
[17/May/2023 20:05:38] "GET /ws/room_page/5/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4248
```

This is my code:

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'playground.apps.PlaygroundConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoWebsite.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer",
    },
}
```

consumer.py

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_id']
        self.room_group_id = 'room_%s' % self.room_id

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_id,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_id,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': 'Hello World!'
            }
        )

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_id,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

routing.py

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/room_page/(?P<room_id>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer),
]
```

javascript file

```js
const roomId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("room-id").textContent);
const url =
  "ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws/room_page/" + roomId + "/";
console.log(url);

const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url);

chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  console.log(data);
  document.querySelector(".user-hello").innerHTML = data.message;
};

chatSocket.onerror = function (error) {
  console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
};
```